# How to insert a list in a list in all possible ways?

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to enumerate all the possible merges of two lists.
In example inserting `"bb"` into `"aaa"` would look like

```
["bbaaa", "babaa", "baaba", "baaab", "abbaa", "ababa", "abaab", "aabba", "aabab", "aaabb"]
```

What I currently did is this

```
import Data.List 

insert'' :: Char -> String -> [(String, String)] -> String
insert'' _ _ ([]) = []
insert'' h b ((x, y):xs) =
  (x ++ [h] ++ (insert' (b, y))) ++ (insert'' h b xs)

insert' :: (String, String) -> String
insert' ([], ys) = ys
insert' (xs, ys) = 
  insert'' h b lists
  where
     h = head xs
     b = tail xs
     lists = zip (tails ys) (inits ys)
```

This returns for `("aaa", "bb")`

```
"bbaaababaaabaababbaababaababbabababb"
```

a concatenated string, I tried making it a list of strings, but I just cannot wrap my head around this function. I always seems to get infinite type construction.

How could I rewrite the function, so it would return a list of strings?

Comment: Type signature please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An other implementation idea as in Daniel Wagners first post is to choose in each step a element from one of the lists and prepending it to the results generated by the function called with only the remaining parts of the list:

```
interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
interleave xs           []           = [xs]
interleave []           ys           = [ys]
interleave xs@(x : xs') ys@(y : ys') = 
  map (x :) (interleave xs' ys) ++ map (y :) (interleave xs ys')
```

For your intial example this produces:

```
ghci> interleave "bb" "aaa"
["bbaaa","babaa","baaba","baaab","abbaa","ababa","abaab","aabba","aabab","aaabb"]
```

Comment: This is my favorite by far. It's exactly the solution I came up with, modulo some style/naming changes. I think it's much simpler to think of it this way (walk through the lists, choosing one element nondeterministically from them at each step).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one implementation idea: for each element in the first list, we will choose (nondeterministically) a position in the second list to insert it, then recurse. For this to work, we first need a way to nondeterministically choose a position; thus:

```
choose :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
choose = go [] where
    go before xs = (before, xs) : case xs of
        []   -> []
        x:xs -> go (x:before) xs
```

For example:

```
> choose "abcd"
[("","abcd"),("a","bcd"),("ba","cd"),("cba","d"),("dcba","")]
```

Now we can use this tool to do the insertion:

```
insert :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
insert [] ys = [ys]
insert (x:xs) ys = do
    (before, after) <- choose ys
    rest <- insert xs (reverse after)
    return (before ++ [x] ++ rest)
```

In ghci:

```
> insert "ab" "cde"
["abcde","aebcd","adebc","acdeb","cabde","caebd","cadeb","dcabe","dcaeb","edcab"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I will give the minimal change needed to fix the code you already have (without completely rewriting your code). The first change needed is to update your type signatures to return lists of strings:

```
insert'' :: Char -> String -> [(String, String)] -> [String]
insert' :: (String, String) -> [String]
```

Now your compiler will complain that the first clause of `insert'` is returning a `String` instead of a `[String]`, which is easily fixed:

```
insert' ([], ys) = [ys]
```

...and that the second clause of `insert''` is trying to append a `String` to a `[String]` when running `[h] ++ insert' (b, y)`. This one takes some thinking to figure out what you really meant; but my conclusion is that instead of `x ++ [h] ++ insert' (b, y)`, you really want to run `\t -> x ++ [h] ++ t` for each element in `insert' (b, y)`. Thus:

```
insert'' h b ((x, y):xs) =
  (map (\t -> x ++ [h] ++ t) (insert' (b, y))) ++ (insert'' h b xs)
```

The complete final code is:

```
import Data.List 

insert'' :: Char -> String -> [(String, String)] -> [String]
insert'' _ _ ([]) = []
insert'' h b ((x, y):xs) =
  (map (\t -> x ++ [h] ++ t) (insert' (b, y))) ++ (insert'' h b xs)

insert' :: (String, String) -> [String]
insert' ([], ys) = [ys]
insert' (xs, ys) = 
  insert'' h b lists
  where
     h = head xs
     b = tail xs
     lists = zip (tails ys) (inits ys)
```

Now ghci will happily produce good answers:

```
> insert' ("aaa", "bb")
["bbaaa","babaa","baaba","baaab","abbaa","ababa","abaab","aabba","aabab","aaabb"]
```